# Table Select Filtering with AlpineJS from Fetch

Tags: select, filter, dropdown, alpine.js

I am trying to display filtered results from a `<select>` element in AlpineJS, and then display the filtered results in the table. I have search working from fetching my API, but I haven't the slightest clue how to filter from a select menu on change.

**The API results look like this:**

```json
{
  "id": 36700,
  "title": "Product",
  "url": "/products/product-name",
  "productDetails": [
    {
      "productNumber": "3263827",
      "characterHeight": "-",
      "characterType": "other",
      "color": "Green/Red",
      "dataRate": null,
      "datasheet": "/writable/data-sheets/product-name.pdf",
      "forwardCurrent": "35 mA",
      "usiLink": null,
      "vout": null
    }
  ]
},
```

There are obviously more than one, but they share the same `productDetails` with different values.

My goal is to loop through all the products, and filter based off of `color` for example. I would like all the color values to be in select element options, and then display the results of the table based off the filter selected.

**This is what my search code looks like:**

```html
<div class="table-wrapper" x-data="loadProducts()" x-init="fetchProducts()">
    <div class="table-filters">
        <div class="table-filters--search">
            <label class="table-filters--heading">Search</label>
            <input 
                type="search" 
                x-ref="searchField" 
                x-model="search" 
                x-on:keydown.window.prevent.slash="$refs.searchField.focus()" 
                placeholder="Search for an employee..."
            />
        </div>
    </div>

    <table class="table" id="productLineTable">
        <tbody>
            <tr x-show="isLoading">
                <td colspan="100%">
                    <div x-show="isLoading">Loading...</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <template x-for="product in filteredProducts">
                <tr>
                    <td x-text="product.title"></td>
                    <td x-text="product.productDetails[0].productNumber"></td>
                    <td x-text="product.productDetails[0].characterHeight"></td>
                    <td x-text="product.productDetails[0].characterType"></td>
                    <td x-text="product.productDetails[0].color"></td>
                    <td x-text="product.productDetails[0].dataRate"></td>
                    <td x-text="product.productDetails[0].datasheet"></td>
                    <td x-text="product.productDetails[0].forwardCurrent"></td>
                    <td x-text="product.productDetails[0].usiLink"></td>
                    <td x-text="product.productDetails[0].vout"></td>
                </tr>
            </template>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>


<script>
    function loadProducts() {
        return {
            search: "",
            products: [],
            isLoading: false,
            fetchProducts() {
                this.isLoading = true;
                fetch('https://api-endpoint-url.json')
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(response => {
                        this.isLoading = false;
                        this.products = response.data.map(data => data);
                })
            },
            get filteredProducts() {
                if (this.search === "") {
                    return this.products;
                }
                return this.products.filter((item) => {
                    return (item.title + item.productDetails[0].productNumber)
                    .toLowerCase()
                    .includes(this.search.toLowerCase());
                });
            },
        };
    }
</script>
```

The search code filters in the `input` field just the `title` and `productNumber` of whatever is typed in that `input`.

Again, **my goal** is to loop the products with `x-for` in a `select` element with `option` values (again using color as the example). When one `option` is selected, I would like the results to filter in the table.